# Confusion in generic List<> hierarchy

Tags: java, generics, collections

[Wildcards and Subtyping - Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html)

> This document has a diagram shows the relationships between several List classes declared with both upper and lower bounded wildcards. The relationship as depicted in the picture below:

[image: Generic list hierarchy]

In the right side hierarchy, `List<? super Number>` is sub type to `List<? super Integer>`. Isn't it confusing?

As far as I interpret, `List<? super Number>` can be represented by any `List<type>` where `type` is either `Number` or super class of `Number`. Same logic holds true for `List<? super Integer>` also. So how can `List<? super Number>` be a sub type of `List<? super Integer>`?

Comment: So a `List<? super Integer>` is a list where `type` is either `Integer` or a super class of `Integer`. Is `Number` a super class of `Integer`?

Comment: yes, Number is super class of Integer

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19739576/2711488) might be helpful…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `List<? super Number>` can only hold `Number` and its super classes, while `List<? super Integer>` can hold the same + integers.

You can think about it this way: if the item type is more restrictive, then a list of such items is lower in the inheritance hierarchy. You can put a `List<? super Number>` in a variable of type `List<? super Integer>`, but not the other way around.

Look at how the item types include each other, this might help you:

[image]